# How set the image height to 100vh in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

(sorry for the probable mistakes, I'm not a native english speaker)
I'm trying to work after another developer on a wordpress website. I am triyng desperately to get a fullwidth image to cover 100vh in height too, but whatever I do, I get the div to 100vh, but the image keep the same size. I've tried in the inspector and if I directly apply the style
`min-height : 100vh;`

it works perfectly but I cannot found anywhere in wordpress to apply this style to the image directly. I even tried via a child selector in the global custom css

```
#my-image-id img
{
    min-height : 100vh;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="title-image" class="et_pb_module et_pb_fullwidth_image et_pb_fullwidth_image_0"> 
    <img src="PRIVATE.jpg" alt="" title="" srcset="PRIVATE.jpg 3408w, PRIVATE.jpg 300w, PRIVATE.jpg 768w, PRIVATE.jpg 1024w, PRIVATE.jpg 1080w" sizes="(max-width: 3408px) 100vw, 3408px"> 
</div>
```

or in the custom css of the element, it's like wordpress just cannot read it, the property isn't even present in the inspector (not even striked). (And I tried to add an "!important" despite everything, it changed nothing)
Thank you already !

Comment: If it works in the inspector, then there could be a few things - 1) There's another style that's overriding what you are doing because it's more specific; 2). The CSS is cached and you need to clear your browser cache; 3) `#my-image-id` seems like it's the `id` on the img tag, so you are actually not applying the styles to the correct element. How about `#my-image-id { min-height: 100vh }` instead?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer ! 
1) In the inspector, if another style is overriding this one, I should see my line but striked, I think, but it's not appearing at all
2)I tried to clear the browser cache but it didn't work
3) Yeah, that was what I was thinking at first, but I saw that when I added the line on my element (#my-image-id) it was instead added on a div around the image, that's what I tried this method. I tried again using the code you gave just in case but it's not working either :/

Comment: Please post your HTML for this section as well - without it we're just guessing.

Comment: So I'm absolutely new to wordpress but since I use the basic fullwidth image from divi builder I don't think I can give you any specific html (can I ?) I can just show you how it looks in my builder : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/10/mwkb.png

Comment: I'm very familiar with Divi, but yes, you can give the HTML. Just copy the source code from that section. You can get that from the inspector.

Comment: ok thanks, do you mean this : ```<div id="title-image" class="et_pb_module et_pb_fullwidth_image et_pb_fullwidth_image_0">
    
    
    <img src="PRIVATE.jpg" alt="" title="" srcset="PRIVATE.jpg 3408w, PRIVATE.jpg 300w, PRIVATE.jpg 768w, PRIVATE.jpg 1024w, PRIVATE.jpg 1080w" sizes="(max-width: 3408px) 100vw, 3408px">
   
   </div>``` ?

Comment: I've added your code (without all the srcset information) and it appears that 100vh is working as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/wd2bmuv4/ - normally SO does not allow external links, but do you have a link to the site you can share?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's more of a wordpress problem than a code problem ... The website is https://www.enkairos.fr/ (but the problematic page is of course not published) I will delete the link as soon as the problem is solved ^^